# Regex pregmatch not correct "sometimes"

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a preg_match_all with a regexpression, that should take a youtube´s video number and place it in the array, so the more youtube videos there is, the more arrays it makes. Here's the result, that are correct:

**C1**

```
Array ( [0] => j5-yKhDd64s ) 1Array ( [0] => j5-yKhDd64s ) 1Array ( [0] => j5-yKhDd64s ) 1
```

Now, my problem is sometimes this occurs:

**C2**

```
Array ( [0] => _dKtoRU7Tlk http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_dKtoRU7Tlk http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_dKtoRU7Tlk ) 1
```

See the difference? At **C1** it takes the video id correct in the ararys and so, the **C2** grabs one and then fails and takes the rest in to the array.

The **C1** youtube links was like this:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5-yKhDd64s&feature=email&email=comment_reply_received
>   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5-yKhDd64s&feature=email&email=comment_reply_received
>   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5-yKhDd64s&feature=email&email=comment_reply_received

The **C2** youtube links was like this:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_dKtoRU7Tlk
>   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_dKtoRU7Tlk
>   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_dKtoRU7Tlk

the difference is that there is the &feature... in the **C1**. I think its because my regex isnt fully optimal?

```
    if (preg_match_all("#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+#", $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
      foreach($matches as $m) {
   echo print_r($m);
      }
    }
    $nContent = preg_replace("#(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?youtube\.com/(?:[^\s]*)#", '', $content);
    echo $nContent;
```

How can i fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regexp:

```
#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+#
```

boils down to three alternative parts:

```
(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)
(?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]+
(?<=v=)[^&\n]+
```

The `(?<=...)` is called a lookbehind assertion and in two of these parts you see it looks for `v=`.

In the first alternative, it looks for `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+` followed by `&`. (which is a lookahead assertion: `(?=...)`)

The second alternative doesn't apply in this case.

In the third alternative, it looks for anything until hitting `&` or `\n`.

Your example doesn't fit correctly on any of those. The easiest fix would be to change the last part:

```
(?<=v=)[^&\n]+
```

to

```
(?<=v=)[^&\s]+
```

so it will stop matching on `&` or any whitespace (`\s`).

Or a better advice: just rewrite the whole thing to really parse the url in a normal way, saving some headaches in the future.

Comment: Thank you! I would like to know alittle more about what you had in mind about the last "better" advice. "Parse the url in a normal way", what do you mean by this, little example?

Comment: @Karem: E.g. by matching entire url's from the text (`#http://[^\s]+#`) and having a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php, then take the query part and use `parse_str` to break it into separate vars.

Comment: So you mean by first match if theres any link, and then take the link take query and take ?v to get the videolink.. correct?

Comment: how should i match? if(preg_match(.. and can i make it work too with multiple links like i have with this?

Comment: @Karem: see the very helpful answer from @philonous below!

Answer (score 2):

Following mvds's answer and comments:

```
$parsed_url = parse_url("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5-yKhDd64s&feature=email&email=comment_reply_received");
parse_str($parsed_url["query"],$output);
echo $output['v'];
```

Comment: Thanks! And @Karem, to get the urls from any text, use `preg_match_all("#http://[^\s]+#i",$txt,$matches)` and then loop the above snippet over the matches using `foreach ( $matches[0] as $url ) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Edit: this one fishes out any youtube video link,
changed it so it stops on whitespace, linebreak or "&"

hope this gives you a start

```
"{youtube.com/watch[?]v=([a-z0-9_-]*?)[^&\s]+}i"
```